# Testing for ARCH Process

Tags: time-series, heteroscedasticity, garch

I have sales data that I think would be best modeled with an ARCH model.

I believe the following is true, but I'm not sure:

If the residuals are regressed against the sales data using the equation $e_t=b_0+b_1*X_t$, where $e$ represents the residual terms from the original regression and $X$ represents the sales data, if $b_1$ is statistically different from zero, then the regression model contains an ARCH process.

Is what I'm saying true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true. This is conditional heteroskedasticity, but not *autoregressive* conditional heteroskedasticity (ARCH). The latter is characterized by autocorrelation between squared residuals and their lags.

You could test for ARCH patterns up to order $m$ by checking the joint statistical significance of all slope coefficients in the model
$$
e^2_t=\alpha_0+\alpha_1 e^2_{t−1}+\dots+\alpha_m e^2_{t−m}+u
$$
in the Lagrange multiplier form: take $R^2$ from the regression and multiply it by the number of observations $T$; this will be distributed as $\chi^2(m)$ under the null of no ARCH effects. This is known as ARCH-LM test. See more in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your question. Probably you meant regressing the SQUARED error against your independent variables but I agree with the answer given by @Richard.

When testing for conditional heterocedasticity you normally is interested in analysing if the error variance of your model depends on the variables included in this model. To analyse this, you should regress the squared error (generally standardised) against ***X***. On the other hand, to test for ARCH effect (i.e., the presence of autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity), you should test the lagged squared residuals.